# <ul> within another <ul> inherits style

Tags: css, inline, block, html-lists

I have the following structure in some HTML:

```
<ul class="li_inline">
    <li>
        <ul class="li_block">
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff under stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="li_block">
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff under stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With the CSS like this:

```
.li_inline li
{
    display: inline;
}

.li_block li
{
    display: block;
}
```

What I would like to happen is to have the two inner `<ul>`s side by side, but any `<li>`s inside them to be below each other. This is so I can get a sidebar and main body side by side, but elements inside them behave normally (ie. one below the other).

Can someone suggest some CSS I can use so that the inner (`li_block`) lists' `<li>` elements are displayed as block elements, but the `<ul>`s themselves are displayed side by side?

Thanks,

James

Comment: You might want to look at http://phrogz.net/JS/ul2menu/purecss_testsuite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a reset rule.

```
ul ul { list-style:none; padding: 5px 20px; margin: 5px 10px; }
```

In your case using the `!important` can get your job done. But try not to use it

### UPDATE

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/KHjmP/ (FF3+, Safari 4+, IE8+)

Comment: Thanks for giving a solution not using floats. I would use them, but don't like them; they screw up layouts sometimes and are a pain. I'll try this solution when I can get to my PC with code on it, and get back to you :-)

Comment: wait, I will create a fiddle with your solution

Comment: Ha ha thanks Starx :-) I'm at college right now (lunch break), so I can't code.

Comment: @JamWaffles, I seem to have forgotten about this. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/KHjmP/

Answer (score 1):

it ain't pretty but you get the jist of it :)

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <ul class="li_block" style="float: left;">
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff under stuff</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="li_block" style="float: left;">
            <li>Stuff</li>
            <li>Stuff under stuff</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see my comment on Starx's answer. I'd use floats, but I'd like a better solution; they are a real pain sometimes.

Comment: You could use display: inline-block instead of floats - the markup you have is really not optimal for the browser, keeping it simpler will benefit both you and the user

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        ul.outer{}

        ul.outer > li{
            float: left;
        }

        ul.outer > li > ul > li{
            display: block;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="outer">
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>1.1</li>
                    <li>1.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>2.1</li>
                    <li>2.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see my comment on Starx's answer. I'd use floats, but I'd like a better solution; they are a real pain sometimes.

Comment: I also use floats and really love them. I mostly use them in conjunction with a surrounding <fieldset></fieldset>. The fieldset wraps around the whole innerhtml that uses floats, so no need to use a <br style="clear:both; />. I'll show an example using that fiddle (never used it before)

Answer (score 0):

```
.li_inline li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.li_block li {
    display: block;
    clear:both; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something as simple as the following. I tested it in Firefox, Chrome and IE7.

```
.li_inline > li {
    display: inline;
}
.li_inline > li > ul  {
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fzBnG/

Comment: Works in IE8 (OMG!). If Starx's answer doesn't work, I'll use floats.

Comment: Alright, just remember that the floats still conform to the .li_inline bounding box, so if you set the width to that too low, it will still wrap, which is expected.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks for everyone's help! I'm really sorry to look like I'm ignoring your hard efforts away, but I *have* taken note of all your answers, and they're all very handy.

The solution I have come up with is to simply use `display: inline-block` for both inner `ul`s, with the outer one left default.

Once again, thanks for your help everyone.

James